# Complexity of $a\binom{x}{2} +by = c$

Tags: complexity-theory, number-theory, integer-programming

[Manders and Adleman](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/800113.803627) showed that it is NP-complete to decide given integers $a, b, c \geq 0$ in binary encoding whether $ax^2 + by = c$ has a solution over the non-negative integers. What is known about the complexity of deciding whether $a\binom{x}{2} +by = c$ has a solution? Here, $\binom{x}{2} = \frac12 x(x-1)$ is the binomial coefficient.

Comment: It's likely also NP-complete. You can try proving this yourself.

Comment: It appears that the problem is NP-complete and [we did prove that](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.09009.pdf).